# How does yarn honor spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

Tags: apache-spark

When we submit spark application on yarn, we can specify the following two executor memory related configuration:

1. spark.executor.memory
2. spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead

`spark.executor.memory` is for on heap memory, and `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is for off heap memory.

But when we request container from yarn, we simply ask `spark.executor.memory + spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` memory, we didn't tell yarn how much memory is for on heap and how much is for off heap, then how does yarn container know how much memory should be allocated on heap and how much should be allocated off heap?